# Banido do chat por postar músicas do resident evil?

Tags: suporte

Fui bloqueado no chat por publicar uma música do resident evil. E ainda por cima por "Conteúdo Inapropriado". Era só uma música, como muitas outras que foram publicadas lá.

O que houve de errado dessa vez, já que sempre que há banimento não há uma explicação mais específica?

Músicas de suspense agora será considerado conteúdo inapropriado?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O link do "vídeo" (na verdade só tem uma capa do Resident Evil), é esse aqui:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kyxi1VszT6k&list=PLG44k5ELt50trH_Kwrz58AU-7ZunQciZN&index=5

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não sei se foste tu que puseste para fechar, mas eu deixaria aberto, para quem no futuro tiver os mesmos problemas.

Comment: @JorgeB. eu botei pra fechar quando estava com raiva. Vou tirar.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Era, pelas minhas contas, o seu milionésimo link pra trilha sonora de Resident Evil no chat hoje. Posso ter errado por uns 2 ou 3 mil, mas confio na minha conta. 
Você tinha colocado um link pra outra música de RE [5 minutos antes](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31983721#31983721), e pingado 3 pessoas sem motivo nenhum.

Além de já ter recebido uma sinalização mais cedo, depois de ter botado link pra [3 outros vídeos de Resident Evil](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31880269#31880269) num intervalo de 5 minutos.

**Pare de floodar o chat**. Ele é descontraído, deixa você passar tempo, bater papo com o pessoal e se divertir. Mas ainda é um chat de programação. Tem gente lá querendo conversar sobre outras coisas também, e não tem que ficar assistindo uma pessoa só dominando a janela inteira.

Comment: Agora fiquei como vontade de adicionar uma funcionalidade pro add-on que limpe um pouco o chat

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Algum tempo atrás alguém tinha feito algo que apagava todos os one-boxing (imagens, vídeos, links, etc) do chat. Mas flag também funciona contra flood `;)`

Comment: Os links acho que pode ser exagero, mas tudo que exibe alguma imagem pode ser incomodo mesmo (apesar que eu não ligo, geralmente continuo). Se me sentir incomodado pode ter certeza que irei usar as ferramentas que o site já nos dispõe :D

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu me referia aos links que recebem one boxing, tipo os da Wikipedia ou Amazon. Eles ocupam bem mais espaço que o normal, o que ajuda muito mas se torna cansativo bem rápido se mal utilizado.

Comment: é que eu não conhecia o termo, mas entendi agora

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Tem o [SOClearChat](https://github.com/lbotinelly/SOClearChat) do [OnoSendai](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/109943/onosendai). Pode conversar com ele e ver a possibilidade de adicionar. Ele funciona muito bem

Comment: Tenho de concordar com o @Gabe tem de ter o mínimo de cuidado com o chat.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento @Gabe. Eu vou tomar mais cuidado com os excessos.